# LR Edit in PS, edited image does not show in LR

Tags: lightroom, photoshop, adobe

I was having an issue with Lightroom CC 2015 freezing and found the suggestion about changing the useAutoBahn setting to false, which I did and indeed the freezing seems to have stopped. But now an older problem seems to have cropped back. I edit a lot of my images from LR to PS and normally when I save my PS changes, close the PS image and return to LR the new image shows up. But now it does not. I know LR has the new image from PS since the original image in LR shows up as a 2 of 2. What I then need to do is exit LR and re-start it back up and the PS image now appears in the filmstrip. Any ideas? (this is a very old issue going back to LR v1.